# Query SQL retornar registros somente depois de 2 dias anteriores a hoje

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Galera, como sou novato em SQL, preciso de uma ajuda. Preciso trazer apenas os registros que não houveram movimentações há mais de dois dias.

A query abaixo está trazendo todos sem essa condição. Até fiz um teste utilizando o datediff, mas não sei ao certo se era isso mesmo.

Trazendo todos os registros essa condição

```
Qtde    Data
5000    18-07-2017
5001    18-07-2017
5002    25-07-2017
```

Porém, era para trazer somente os do dia 18, pois está há mais de 2 dias em relação a data de hoje. Abaixo é a query que tentei fazer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
S.SolID AS [Qtde - Chamados em Pausa],
MAX(CONVERT(DATE,T.TraData,103))
FROM Solicitacao S
LEFT JOIN Usuario U ON U.UsuID = S.UsuIDResponsavel
LEFT JOIN Tramite T ON T.SolID = S.SolID
WHERE S.VencimentoPausado = 1 AND
      T.TraData < DATEDIFF ( DAY ,2, getdate())
group by s.SolID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tente o seguinte código, veja se funciona porque fiz às cegas já que não coloca a estrutura das tabelas e não tenho como testar aqui:

```
SELECT
S.SolID,
T.TraData
FROM Solicitacao S
INNER JOIN Tramite T on T.SolID = S.SolID and 
                    T.TraID = (SELECT TOP 1 
                                X.TraID 
                               FROM Tramite X 
                               WHERE X.SolID = S.SolID ORDER BY X.TraData DESC)
WHERE S.VencimentoPausado = 1 AND 
      cast(T.TraData as date) <= cast(DATEADD(day,-2,getdate()) as date)
```

Comment: Show de Bola Cara. Eu não coloco a estrutura das tabelas, porque é muito grande e alguns caso é inviável de colocar aqui, mas deu certo. Valeu!

Comment: que bom que ajudou, sobre o tamanho, você pode postar a DDL, e sempre coloque o código entre dois acentos agudos ` ou após quatro espaços para que fique formatado, tamanho das perguntas, acredito que não seja problema. Você também pode usar o SQLFiddle, porque ajuda muito na hora de analisar o código e entender a necessidade.